# magento2 rc error?

Tags: magento2, module, magento2-dev-beta

i have custom module it not wordpress magento2-rc2.
it get error

```
Please upgrade your database: Run "bin/magento setup:upgrade" from the Magento root directory. 
The following modules are outdated:
Xyaddons_Backinstock data: current version - none, required version - 2.0.0"
```

when i run command `php -f bin/magento setup:upgrade` get error same.

i check in **Table** setup_module in **database**

```
 module `Xyaddons_Backinstock   schema_version 2.0.0    data_version null
```

**module.xml in etc**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Xyaddons_Backinstock"  setup_version="2.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Backend"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

this file **registration.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Xyaddons_Backinstock',
    __DIR__
);
```

and file **composer.json**

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "files": [ "registration.php" ],
        "psr-4": {
            "Xyaddons\\Backinstock\\": ""
        }
    }
}
```

any help me thank so much.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create registration.php file in root of your module.
    Inside this file you have to declare your magento namespace_modulename.

```
 \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
        \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
        'Vendorname_Modulename', // you can put your module name like Magento_Checkout...
        __DIR__
    );
```

Also you have to declared registration in composer.json file.(for CLI)
    You have to find autoload and insert  "files": [ "registration.php" ] code.

```
"autoload": {
        "files": [ "registration.php" ] ,
        "psr-4": {
            "Vendorname\\Modulename\\": ""
        }      
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: i created two file registration.php and registration.php i root same you. but not success

Comment: you have to create only one file in root with namespace registration.php

Comment: yes. 2 file in Xyaddons/Backinstock/ registration.php , Xyaddons/Backinstock/  composer.json

Comment: plz can you show me, the registration.php file code and composer.json file code

Comment: i edited question

Comment: you can delete those records from setup_module table and delete var cache and generator folder and try again.

Comment: custom module i not active. i don't find it in config.xml in database is not it

Comment: i made it. it not success

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31637/discussion-between-rb-jesadiya-and-xanka).

Answer (score 1):

i am also facing same issue

```
{
    "name": "sugarcode/module-test",
    "description": "N/A",
    "require": {
        "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0",
        "magento/module-config": "100.0.*",
        "magento/module-store": "100.0.*",
        "magento/module-backend": "100.0.*",
        "magento/module-customer": "100.0.*",
        "magento/module-cms": "100.0.*",
        "magento/framework": "100.0.*"
    },
    "type": "magento2-module",
    "version": "100.0.1",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "registration.php"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "Sugarcode\\Test\\": ""
        }
    }
}
```

app\code\Sugarcode\Test\registration.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Sugarcode_Test',
    __DIR__
);
```

app\code\Sugarcode\Test\etc\frontend\routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="test" frontName="test">
            <module name="Sugarcode_Test" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

in my controller i gave exit and echo the text still its redirecting to 404 page and also it will registered in setup_module table but my custom setup is not running no table was created i tried put exit in that insatll file and run upgrade cli but it dint exit it run fully

same module is worked in beta version but in 2.0.0 cr2 i added both file still its not working

can any one verfiy my .json and registration.php and correct me if i did wrong