# Module throwing error after enable, setup:upgrade

Tags: magento2, module

This question has been asked [a](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/90165/magento2-rc-error)
[few](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35859450/how-to-remove-this-error)
[times](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/104592/data-current-version-none-required-version-2-0-0) but no excepted answers, and none of the suggestions worked for me. Here is the error:

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Please upgrade your database: Run "bin/magento setup:upgrade" from the Magento root directory. 
The following modules are outdated:
Dope_CustomModule data: current version - none, required version - 1.0.0
```

Seems simple and the error says to run `setup:upgrade`. Of course I already did that when I installed my module.

I *originally* had a typo in my `registration.php` where I put `Dopes_CustomModule` instead of `Dope_CustomModule`. Magento 2 seems to hate when I rename themes and modules and so I suspect the typo may have caused this problem to persist. The `setup:upgrade` process still went through without error (the error shows up on page load to be clear).

I've cleared `pub/static/*`, `var/di/*` `var/generation/*`, `var/cache/*` and I've triple checked for typos in the code. I enabled/re-enabled several times, I recompiled. Nothing.

I've tried a few times and I notice that the `data_version` column in my `setup_module` is always NULL, resulting in the above error. If I change the NULL value of the `data_version` column in the DB from anything but NULL, including an empty string, my page loads. I did check into this any further, it should be obvious that this "fix" is not really a fix and I'd like something that doesn't require digging into the db, but maybe that helps answer the question.

So why is `data_version` NULL and why am I getting the above error?

```
# File: module.xml:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Dope_CustomModule" setup_version="1.0.0"/>
</config>
```

developer mode Running Magento 2.1.0 CE locally

Comment: Remove entry of `data_version` for your module from `setup_module` and then run upgrade command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok my issue was pretty dumb in the end but here is the answer.

The issue came out of my "simple" module having an issue in it's setup. I included a file, `Setup/InstallData.php` which was copied and modified from an apparently outdated tutorial.

Although I never found the exact issue with my setup, I realized it was causing the problem when I removed the file completely on a whim. Rather than giving me a useful error pointing to the `InstallData.php`, I got the problem mentioned in this question, hence the confusion. I then found a more reliable source for the `InstallData.php` that did what I needed it to do.

So I hope this helps someone with a similar issue. Most people will probably find Ankit Shah's answer to be more relevant but it was not what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Go to `setup_module` Table

Find your module `Dope_CustomModule`.

Make sure `schema_version` & `data_version` should be same as per your current module.

Then run

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Everything works fine